# I didn't understand this open disk question

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[image]

I don't understand why I can't connect the $-1$ and $1$ points with just two line segments. I've tried it in my head and it makes sense to me. Why do I need $3$ line segments? Can somebody draw this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: One could say: by the same reason why you need two segments to connect two points in the open disk. The author assumes that we consider only segments parallel to the axes. You need to go up, then right, then down again.

Comment: @StefanH Why I can't connect then with two line segments? I''m learning so this doesn't makes sense to me

Comment: As I said: The author only takes into account the lines that are parallel to the $x$- or the $y$-axis.

Comment: @user108425, what are the author's definition of "segments" for this part of the book? If we take the usual, standard definition of segment as a finite part of a straight line then the author is wrong, but as Stefan told you already twice it seems to be the author's speaking *only* of segments **parallel** to one of the two axis. Check this

Comment: @StefanH You might as well write that up as an answer to get this off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author takes into account only those lines that are parallel to the $x$- or the $y$-axis. Otherwise, two points $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ in $B_r(0)$, the open ball with radius $r$ and center $0$ could be joined by the path $t\mapsto ty+(1-t)x,\ t\in[0,1]$. This works because 
$||ty+(1-t)x||\le t||y||+(1-t)||x||\le
t\max\{||x||,||y||\}+(1-t)\max\{||x||,||y||\}<1\cdot r$.
In other words, the ball is convex.
But with lines parallel to the axes you need at least two. A simple proof by induction shows that in $\Bbb R^n$ two points differing in $k$ coordinates can be joined by $k$ lines parallel to the axes, but not less. So if $x_1\ne y_1$ and $x_2\ne y_2$, then we need at least two such segments.
In order to show that it can be done with two segments **within** $B$, consider $z=(y_1,x_2)$. Then either $y_1\le x_1$ and thus $||z||\le||x||$, or $y_1>x_1$. In that case, if $x_2\le y_2$, we have $||z||\le||y||$, otherwise $x_2>y_2$. But then $||(x_1,y_2)||\le r$. That means we can either connect $x\to z→y$ or $x→(x_1,y_2)→y$ within $B$.